# Having issues using fdisk and GParted with Lexar 64GB USB, but reading and writing is fine

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, fdisk

I have recently bought a new 64GB Lexar USB with the long model name of LJDV10-64G-000-106, and I am having issues partitioning it. I am able to mount, read and write to the USB without any issues but whenever I try to partition it with GParted it doesn't show up in the dropdown. Also while using the command `sudo fdisk -l` I receive the error `fdisk: unable to seek on /dev/sdc: Invalid argument`. This is a brand new USB so I am not sure why I am having these issues, especially since the device is functioning perfectly with read/write.

I have tried reformatting it on a windows machine but that does not seem to do anything.

For those who want a visual my USB looks almost exactly like

[image: Lexar 8GB USB]

But 64GB rather than 8GB

**Edit:** I have just ran GParted from the terminal and I am getting a similar error, but it may give more information on the issue.

```
Could not determine physical sector size for /dev/sdc.
Using the logical sector size (512).
Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdc
```

Also clearing my USB with /dev/zero fails with the the message

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
dd: writing `/dev/sdc': No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.00167254 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the confusion, the issue wasn't the USB, it was the kernel version I was using. I decided to delete 3.4.0.0 and use the kernel ubuntu provided by default.